# Error at setCurrentTime mediaelements.js

Tags: html, video, skip

I have a Javascript Problem with my Video.
Player is mediaelements.jd player

i skip through the video if the user clicks on radio buttons or other events. But in IE the error console writes after clicking:

```
SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: INDEX_SIZE_ERR (1) 
mediaelement-and-player.js, Zeile 385 Zeichen 3
```

and this line is:

```
384 setCurrentTime: function (time) {
385     this.currentTime = time;
386 },
```

what's the problem here?